# Use Autohotkey to remap the left shift to "(" and the right shift to ")", but I still want to to use either of the shift keys with other keys

Tags: autohotkey

Use Autohotkey to remap the left shift to <kbd>(</kbd> and the right shift to <kbd>)</kbd>, but I still want to to use either of the shift keys with other keys.

So if I tap the left shift, I'd like <kbd>(</kbd> to appear. If I hold left shift and tap `a`, I'd like <kbd>A</kbd>.

The reason for using autohotkey is that I'm already using it to remap my keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LShift UP::Send, (
RShift UP::Send, )
LShift & F13::
RShift & F13::
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? What does LShift & F13 do?

Comment: I guess the answer will die with @william :(

Comment: Finally I find this!! No `F13` will make uppercase letters and puctuations like "!" also trigger ().